# GRT lib, and how to import Native lib on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, machine-learning, android-ndk

I'm working on an Android app (with Android Studio) who is able to understand the activity you are doing with an algorithm of gesture recognition. 
For the algorithm I'm using GRT library available on nickgillian ithub account (I cannot post the link, cause my newbie reputation)

I'm trying to import the GRT (gesture recognition toolkit) on my project, but I'm having some issues, cause I'm new with ndk applications.
For importing the library I followed some tutorials on youtube and this link:

http://hollyhook.de/wp/grt-for-android/

I followed that instead it is for eclipse, adapting the procedure for android studio. I create the jni and the Application.mk and Android.mk. 
For the compiling part I'm using **cygwin64** like I've seen on some video online but when I use the command:
`/cygdrive/C/Programmi/Java/NDK/ndk-build` (The system variables are set with this same path )

The sell I always answer: -bash: /cygdrive/C/Programmi/Java/NDK/ndk-build: No such file or directory

[image: -]

[image: -]

Could someone explain me how can I build this project or a fast mode for doing the same?

Comment: it is also possible that you fall a victim of Windows seamless folder name internationalization. What you see in Explorer as "C:\Programmi\Java" may look different from the cygwin command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working off an old tutorial. We don't ship the ndk-build shell script in the Windows NDKs any more (https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/194). As far as I can tell, there isn't actually a reason to. You should be able to just run ndk-build.cmd and it will work fine. (If anyone has a use case that says otherwise, please speak up!)

If you're only using cygwin because some tutorial said to, you should know that you don't actually need to use cygwin. You can run ndk-build.cmd from the normal Windows command prompt. (In the very distant past cygwin was actually the only way to use the NDK on Windows, which is why some material might say that.)